# Laravel: Routing based on middleware

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

My routes.php file looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@index',
    'as' => 'home',
]);
```

I want to use middleware to check if user is logged in and use a totally different controller like this:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index',
    'as' => 'home',
]);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't modify the controller being used via middleware - is there a reason you don't have a different route for logged out users? And instead catch that they're not logged in using middleware and redirect them to that different route?

Comment: Is there a reason you dont want to use separate routes, eg `/` and `dashboard/`?

Comment: No reason. I just don't want to separate routes, but don't know how. I tried with Route::group(), but it doesn't work

Comment: I can check if user is logged in via controller and then "change" view, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea. What do u think, guys?

Comment: It could be a "good" idea. It just depends on what you're trying to do. If you have a "landing" page that has mutually exclusive functionality depending on your authentication status - then having two completely views (served from within a controller) is dandy. If the feature-set isn't mutually exclusive, I'd suggest including, or suppressing, feature components within the view itself. That said, I can think of a few other ways to change content based on authentication status - but which one is "better" depends on the scope of the project, program philosophy, project type, etc.